# Open my tkinter exe file, when open txt file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter file, that opens txt files and insert that into a Text widget.

I used cx_Freeze to build it to an .exe file, but if I right click and open the txt file with this program it does nothing.

Do anyone know, how van I do that my program automatically read the file, even if it's not opened form the program.

Sorry for my bad english, if I was not clear, I mean the "open the program from the txt file" that if you right-click the .txt file, there is an option "open with..." and I choose my .exe program made in tkinter.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import re
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

def open_nd():
    rawfile = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select file",filetypes = (("Nonexistent documents","*.nd"), ("Exsistant decoded files","*.ed")))
print(rawfile)
file = open(rawfile, "r")
a = file.read()
area = Text(root)
area.pack()
area.insert(END, a)


menu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

filebar=Menu(menu)
menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_nd)

root.mainloop()
```

Again, sorry fo my bad english, and thanks the answers!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right do these steps:

[Right Click -> Open With](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLNFo.png)

[Click here More apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJLem.png)

[Look for another program on this pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5VxU.png)

[Choose your exe here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii8ps.png)

Comment: Yes, that's what I do, but in my exe program, that I choosed, doesn't show the text of the txt file